# Display map on its own line in a text widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, maps

For example,

Lets say I have a map:

```
Map<string, dynamic> myMap = {'zero': 0, 'one': 1, 'two': 2};
```

How can I display these values in a text widget like what is depicted below:

```
Map key-value pairs:
zero: 0
one: 1
two: 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following :

```
Column(
  children: myMap.entries
      .map(
        (e) => Text("${e.key}: ${e.value}"),
      )
      .toList(),
);
```

Comment: perfect. Do you know how make them all values start at the beginning? I did Mainaxisaligment: start but them seem to be centering in the column instead of starting at the begininng

Comment: add MainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, in the Column properties in addition of the mainAxisAlignment:  mainAxisAlignment.start,

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: myMap.entries.toList().length,
        itemBuilder: (cont, index) {
          return Text('${myMap.entries.toList()[index].key.toString()} : ${myMap.entries.toList()[index].value.toString()}');
        },
        )
```